# Andy emulator error the operation was canceled (Mac)

Tags: mac, emulator

I've installed andy andriod emulator, but after opening it I get the error "operation was cancelled (10)" and after clicking [ok] andy closes Automatically. I have a MacBookPro, Mojave 10.14.

It's the same issue as here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52170249/andy-emulator-error-the-operation-was-canceled

But in a Mac. But because I'm not much of a computer person, I can't really apply the PC solution to my Mac :)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Launch the app then go to System Settings>Security and Privacy>General. It will state the app was stopped from loading. Click allow.